# ManyToOne relationship with a String field

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I have two classes: `TranscriptionService` and `TranscriptionConfig`.

`TranscriptionConfig` has a `serviceName` variable, that is a string, with setters and getters.

`TranscriptionService` has no variables or references in the class to `TranscriptionConfig`.

There are two database tables: `transcriptionConfig` and `transcriptionServices`. `transcriptionConfig` has a foreign key between its field `serviceName`, and `name` inside `transcriptionServices`.

An admin should be able to set the string value of `serviceName` inside `transcriptionConfig`. This then references the equivalent string inside `name` in `transcriptionServices`. The `transcriptionServices` entries in the database are pre defined manually, so they never need to be set using an object.

My current hibernate code inside `transcriptionConfig` for the `serviceName` is as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
private String transcriptionService;
```

However, it will not allow me to do this, as a `String` is not an entity. I have tried adding `target-entity` to no avail.

It seems to have a `manyToOne` relationship, it would need to have an instance of the `TranscriptionService` class, but I do not want `transcriptionConfig` to contain this object. It just needs a reference with the names.

How I can use this `ManyToOne` relationship, but just pass around the string for the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat this column as a string value, you don't need to define mapping `@ManyToOne` and use `@JoinColumn`. Just mark it by`@Column`.

You'll need probably to catch `SQLException` in your DAO to handle foreign key constraint.

**Edit:**
You get this exception, because you don't have this key in foreign table. First you need to create row in `TranscriptionService` table.

Comment: I understand the error I'm getting, but there is no way I can see to catch it, as an actual exception is never thrown? The helper is giving an error message, and then hibernate is returning a 403 forbidden. I have other validation to stop the string from being certain things, but the validation exception is never thrown, as the helper causes the code to stop earlier... Any ideas? ( `ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper......` )

Comment: Paste somewhere your code where you do persist() or update() and full stacktrace.

Comment: Code: https://paste.ee/p/QXmGl (this is the lowest level I can legitimately edit, `userProvisioningService.add(user);` adds the user to the database)

Comment: Can you catch this exception with a breakpoint while debugging?

Comment: An exception is never technically thrown, the hibernate sqlexception helper just prints the error and returns 403. There was no place I could catch an SQLException.

Comment: What does "returns 403" mean?

Comment: Hibernate returns a client response of 403:Forbidden, ie. it is forbidden to write that object to the database because of the foreign key constraints.

Comment: method userProvisioningService.add(user); returns integer 403? I don't get it.

Comment: Don't worry, complicated code project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In this case, how to make it clear to developers that it is a ManyToOne related column? Other than using comments